# How to make back consumable in-app product into non-consumable?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, consumption

My android app uses in-app product. It's necessary for me to achieve at the same time two task:

1. **user should have opportunity to buy the product several times**. For that I can make product consumable using consumePurchase method.
2. **I need to have opportunity to check user already paid product**. I can't save it in device because I need to know it even if user change device. I know it can make it only when product is non-consumable using getPurchases method because on consumable product it returns always nothing.

Help me please: how can I achieve this two task at the same time?

May be exist way to return back product from non-consumable into consumable?

Answer (score 0):

store the purchase of the user against his session and device id. Check if the person has purchased the item in your server side

Comment: Could you clarify your answer, please? Can it help if user change his device? Can you give a link discribed saving and getting data from server side?